# Equivalent msbuild command for Publish from VS2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

any idea which is the command for publish in msbuild corresponding to the one in VS2008?
What I want is the resulting output to be the same, without that _PublishedWebSites subdirectory.
Is this achievable from command line or I should use a build file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at the [Vs2008 Web Deployment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx) stuff. Underneath, it uses the [AspNetCompiler Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164291.aspx), so you could hack that into you .*proj file.

Answer (score 11):

Solved this by specifying WebProjectOutputDir property. 
It looks something like this: 
MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild "MyTestProject.sln" /p:OutDir=c:\Project\bin\ /p:WebProjectOutputDir=C:\Project\ /p:Configuration=Debug

Answer (score 3):

You can also check out these blog posts:
- http://blog.m.jedynak.pl/2008/03/publishing-web-application-with-msbuild.html
- http://codingcockerel.co.uk/2008/05/18/how-to-publish-a-web-site-with-msbuild/