# VS2012 MSBuild: Publish a Web Application Project with Existing Publish Profile

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, vs-web-application-project

In the Visual Studio 2012 Build menu, there's a Publish command. In this you can establish profiles which are saved as .pubxml files in the Properties folder of the Project. I have one such profile that's a simple file copy operation - it just compiles the site and dumps it to a folder.

How can I use msbuild at the command line to publish a compiled web application to a folder?

---

### What I've tried

I've tried the example from this question:

[After Publish event in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781799/after-publish-event-in-visual-studio)

And the changes and examples given here:

http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/59/locally-publishing-a-vs2010-asp.net-web-application-using-msbuild

The latter seems to get closest, but it causes every library Project the .csproj I'm attempting to publish from to throw an error:

> Project "MainProj.csproj" (1) is building "ReferencedProj.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
>
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(609,5): error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'ReferencedProj.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Staging'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [ReferencedProj.csproj]
>
> Done Building Project "ReferencedProj.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

This approach is very similar to what's suggested in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077178/176877

The crucial difference may be that I'm in Visual Studio 2012, rather than VS2008 or 2010.

Comment: Do you have the proper platform specified? Have you tried without specifying a platform. IE: just "Configuration='Staging'"

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case this helps anyone, this simple, stripped back approach worked fine for me:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <BuildDependsOn>
        $(BuildDependsOn);
        PublishOtherProject;
    </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="PublishOtherProject"> 
    <MSBuild Projects="pathtomyproject.csproj" Properties="DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=nameOfPublishProfile" />
</Target>
```

The key line being:

```
<MSBuild Projects="pathtomyproject.csproj" Properties="DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=nameOfPublishProfile" />
```