# Changing the ASP.NET build folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have a bare ASP.NET application with only a web.config and global.asax, is it possible to build the application as if i am publishing the entire application to a specific folder (and debugging from that specific folder) instead of VS201x running off of the default bin folder?

i.e.

- x:\path\to\webapp\service\global.asax
- x:\path\to\webapp\service\web.config (transformed)
- x:\path\to\webapp\service\bin\*.*

The reason i want to do this is that this particular ASP.NET web application is dynamically loading assemblies and creating routes dynamically (depending on the classes decorated by a certain attribute, as is basically a WCF service)

so in the end, my build folder would be something like:

- x:\path\to\webapp\service\global.asax
- x:\path\to\webapp\service\web.config (transformed)
- x:\path\to\webapp\service\bin\*.*
- x:\path\to\webapp\plugins\plugin1\*.*
- x:\path\to\webapp\plugins\plugin2\*.*

I can provide additional info if needed

Comment: This question is somewhat similar to what i needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429650/asp-net-webdeploy-include-folder-generated-in-post-build-of-sub-project

Comment: Shadow Wizard's link is exactly what i needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076971/publish-a-web-application-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Visual Studio, right click the ASP.NET project and choose Properties.
2. Go to the Build tab.
3. Click the button marked in red to select new build folder:
   [image]

Edit: figured you actually want to *Publish* the project automatically after successfully building it, so to achive this follow the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077178/447356) to make command line utility that will do that then add the command line as post-build event:

> [image]

Comment: yes of course, but what i need is to simulate a "publish" during a build, so all of the necessary files are copied to another folder (the global.asax and transformed web.config)

Comment: The project folder would be in x:\some\path\to\aspnet\project\ whilst the build (published) folder would be somewhere else like x:\path\to\build\

Comment: You can follow the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7076971/447356) to have command line publish and add the command line as Post-build event.