# ASP.NET project will only look at dll's from bin folder not the output folder I specify

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, web-config

I am getting an error message in the browser saying it can't find the dll's when I put the project output to a different directory(from "bin" to "..\Any\Debug\") in project property-->build. It can find the dll's if I set it to "bin".

I've tried install the necessary dlls to GAC([Drag and drop a DLL to the GAC ("assembly") in windows server 2008 .net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787607/drag-and-drop-a-dll-to-the-gac-assembly-in-windows-server-2008-net-4-0)), try to change the path in web.config ([probing privatePath and subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931312/probing-privatepath-and-subdirectories) )and use Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable ([Set Custom Path to Referenced DLL's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892492/set-custom-path-to-referenced-dlls) ). I haven't found the right code to try the Post-build event command line([Changing the ASP.NET build folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208814/changing-the-asp-net-build-folder)).

Is there anyone that has been able to find out how to work around this? I'm sure something like this should work but it's not working for me:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="..\Any\Debug"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I have tried using relative path and hard coded path.

Comment: What is wrong with putting the DLLs in the bin directory? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have other non ASP.NET projects outputting the dll's in one folder and I wanted to put the dll's in one place