# How to copy all files of .net builded project to another folder like Visual Studio do before publish webSite?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, command-line, publish, aspnet-compiler

I'm building a tool that build .net projects with MSBuild command, and after this run the aspnet_compiler to precompile website and publish it programmatically. The problem is that some open source projects that I download give errors in some files. After this I search the differences between my approach of Visual studio and realize that this files in Visual Studio are Ignored. Also realize that visual studio first copy all files needed from the source folder of project to another folder, namely "obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source". In this folder are only the files used in project and mentioned in the project file "web.csproj", and files that gave me error don't are copied.

So my question is, someone knows a way to do the step of copy only used files mentioned in .csproj?
I think this will resolve my problem. In projects well configured the app works perfectly.

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Where are you getting the errors (compile, copy, etc.)?  What are you doing now to deploy your code?  What makes you think that copying only the used files will solve your problem?

Comment: I have getting errors in aspnet_compiler, for example "/install/controls/connectionstring.ascx(1): error ASPPARSE: Could not load type 'MettleSystems.dashCommerce.Web.install.controls.connectionstring'.

Now I'm building the solution with MSbuild and in the next step compiling with aspnet_compiler. I think the problem can be solved copuing the used files because this file, in visual studio publish, is ignored, and if open "web.csproj" xml file this file that gave me the error isn't mentioned there.

Comment: also the file mentioned don't appear in solution Explorer view in Visual Studio. Because of all this I think that maybe it's garbage or code not used, and want to remove this programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. After building the solution with msbuild, just run msbuild again, but this time with some parameters that I found in web and here, [Publish a Web Application from the Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076971/publish-a-web-application-from-the-command-line) to copy files mentioned in csproj to a destination folder. In these step are needed to copy also all dll files in bin folder because of some dependencies, for last run aspnet_compiler.

Above are a simple example of commands.

```
>msbuild.exe D:\proj\solution.sln

>msbuild.exe "D:\proj\webproj\proj.csproj" /t:_CopyWebApplication /p:OutDir="D:\proj\tmpFolder" /p:WebProjectOutputDir="D:\proj\tmpFolder"

>xcopy "D:\proj\webproj\bin" "D:\proj\tmpFolder\bin" /I /S /Y

>aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p "D:\proj\tmpFolder" -d "D:\publishFolder"
```

I hope this can help someone.